# JSF Navigation issue Facelets and Beans

Tags: jsf, navigation, facelets

I have an issue with navigation in my simple jsf system.

I have `MainBean` that has two methods: `public String register()` and `public String login().`

I have played with `faces-config.xml` for several hours and I feel like I miss something very important because I think like I have tried all simple solutions so far :).

I have added the MySQL connector (jdbc) to Tomcat's lib folder and I am able to register the table to MySQL database. It even allows my users to log in to the page.

The only problem is that I can't use navigation in any other page than `login.xhtml`. Seems like navigation is only active on this one. I tried to use `<from-view-id>*` but is no joy. I am sure that there is a simple fix for that and someone will come up with correct solution soon. Let's skip all the MySQL part and try to fix the navigation issue please.

Here is the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
  <application>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>    
  </application>
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>mainBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>dk.itu.beans.MainBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>registerBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>dk.itu.beans.RegisterBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/login_failed.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>sign</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/register.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
  <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/login_failed.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>back</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Here the last navigation-rule from `login_failed.xhtml` does not work at all.

Here is `login.xhtml` (which is the main - starting view):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<body>
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="helloForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
   <h:outputText value="Username2:" />
   <h:inputText id="username" value="#{mainBean.username}" />
   <h:outputText value="Password:" />
   <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{mainBean.password}" />
  </h:panelGrid>
  <h:commandButton value="Log in" action="#{mainBean.login}" />
  <h:commandButton value="Sign up" action="sign" />
 </h:form>
  </ui:define>  
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
login_failed.xhtml:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<body>
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="body">
<f:view>
 <h:outputText value="Unknown username or password." />
 <h:commandButton value="Sign up" action="sign" />
 <h:commandButton value="Log in" action="back" />
</f:view>
</ui:define>  
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I tried many options. I used `action="#{mainBean.register})"` method that returns "sign" string and none of these worked. There is one more file (not specified in `faces-config.xml` file, because did not work either - but going from `login.xhtml` by button works fine. I tried to manage navigation from `login_failed.xhtml` first, then I will apply the same rule for registration to come back to login page when customer registers his nick name).

Here is `register.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<body>
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="helloForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
       <h:outputText value="User Name:"/>
      <h:inputText type="text" id="userName" value=""/>
   <h:outputText value="Password:"/>
      <h:inputSecret type="text" id="userPassword" value=""/>
      <h:outputText value="Member Level:"/>
      <h:selectOneRadio value="">
                              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Platinium" itemValue="Platinum" />
                              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Gold" itemValue="Gold" />
                              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Normal" itemValue="Normal" />
                          </h:selectOneRadio>
      <h:outputText value="Full Name:"/>
      <h:inputText type="text" id="userFull" value=""/>
      <h:outputText value="Address:"/>
      <h:inputTextarea type="text" id="userAddress" value=""/>
      <h:outputText value="Zip Code:"/>
      <h:inputText type="text" id="userZip" value=""/>
      <h:outputText value="City:"/>
      <h:inputText type="text" id="userCity" value=""/>
   <h:commandButton value="Sign Up" action="#{mainBean.register}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>  
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Basicaly `mainBean.register` now calls the database and returns string, but obviously it doesn't navigate to any view (but gives an entry to database).

I believe it is simple fix for most of the experienced web developers and any help will be greatly appreciated.

I use eclipse, tomcat 6 and Widows Vista if that helps :)

Thank you in advance.
Kindest regards.

Answer (score 2):

In general I can recommend trying to get something simple working prior to moving on to the advanced stuff like templating. A few pointers:

- Use **redirect** in the navigation rule on the login page. This way you don't need any special hoopla to get the back button working.
- Its generally a bad idea to create the session bean prior to the login being validated. A common solution is to use a request scoped **identity bean** on the login page, then inject this into a **LoginAction** which validates the credentials and creates the user session.

I have a rather complete Facelets/JSF2 sample online that demonstrates this behaviour:

- Facelets login [login.xhtml](http://hg.randompage.org/java/src/tip/projects/bookmarking/frontend/jsf/src/main/webapp/login.xhtml) and [welcome.xhtml](http://hg.randompage.org/java/src/tip/projects/bookmarking/frontend/jsf/src/main/webapp/welcome.xhtml) page
- JSF [faces-config.xml](http://hg.randompage.org/java/src/tip/projects/bookmarking/frontend/jsf/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml)
- Request scoped [identity](http://hg.randompage.org/java/src/tip/projects/bookmarking/frontend/jsf/src/main/java/org/randompage/bookmarking/frontend/model/Identity.java) bean and the [login action](http://hg.randompage.org/java/src/tip/projects/bookmarking/frontend/jsf/src/main/java/org/randompage/bookmarking/frontend/action/LoginAction.java) that validates user credentials.

Feel free apply the copy-paste design pattern to your code as much as you like.

Comment: These links are broken. The answer is still somewhat useful, but any chance you can fix those links?

Answer (score 0):

`UICommand` components ought to be placed inside an `UIForm` element. In `login_failed.xhtml` you're forgotten use a `h:form`. Add it and it will work.